# Parsing from Excel multisheet file: List comprehension between columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas, parsing, list-comprehension

I am trying to parse an excel file that has many sheets. Each sheet has a column that has information  as follows (3 sheets=3 columns):

```
ReceivedEmail    OpenedEmail    ClickedURL
aaaa@aaa.com     gggg@aaa.com   aaaa@aaa.com
bbbb@aaa.com     dddd@aaa.com   rrrr@aaa.com
cccc@aaa.com     rrrr@aaa.com
dddd@aaa.com     aaaa@aaa.com
eeee@aaa.com     oooo@aaa.com
ffff@aaa.com
gggg@aaa.com
rrrr@aaa.com
qqqq@aaa.com
oooo@aaa.com
```

What I want is a single table that retains the first column of sheet one i.e. the one that has all data regarding ReceivedEmail (persons we mass e-mailed). The next columns should be each first column of subsequent sheet but instead of repeating the e-mails, I want to use list comprehension to check if OpenedEmail exists in ReceivedEmail and give *1* else give *0*.

Here's what I did so far:

```
import pandas as pd
xl = pd.ExcelFile(path_to_file)
xl.sheet_names
['ReceivedEmail', 'OpenedEmail', 'ClickedURL']
df = xl.parse(sheet_name=xl.sheet_names[0], header=None)
df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]:xl.sheet_names[0]}, inplace=True);
df.columns[0]
['ReceivedEmail']
# then I created a buffer dataframe to check next columns
df_buffer = xl.parse(sheet_name=xl.sheet_names[1], header=None)
df_buffer.rename(columns={df_buffer.columns[0]:xl.sheet_names[1]}, inplace=True);
```

But then when I run list comprehension like this:

```
df[df_buffer.columns[0]] = [1 if x in df[df.columns[0]] else 0 for x in df_buffer[df_buffer.columns[0]]]
```

I get an error:

*ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index*

Any clue how to solve this error or handle the problem in a smart way? I am doing manually to see if it works, then I could do a looping later, but I am stuck with the error.

End result should be:

```
ReceivedEmail    OpenedEmail    ClickedURL
aaaa@aaa.com         1              1
bbbb@aaa.com         0              0      
cccc@aaa.com         0              0     
dddd@aaa.com         1              0
eeee@aaa.com         0              0    
ffff@aaa.com         0              0  
gggg@aaa.com         1              0
rrrr@aaa.com         1              1
qqqq@aaa.com         0              0
oooo@aaa.com         1              0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) with parameter `sheetname=None` for return all sheets to ordered dictionary of DataFrames:

*Notice:*

*Each sheet have one column.*

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheetname=None)
print (dfs)
OrderedDict([('ReceivedEmail',               a
0  aaaa@aaa.com
1  bbbb@aaa.com
2  cccc@aaa.com
3  dddd@aaa.com
4  eeee@aaa.com
5  ffff@aaa.com
6  gggg@aaa.com
7  rrrr@aaa.com
8  qqqq@aaa.com
9  oooo@aaa.com), ('OpenedEmail',               a
0  gggg@aaa.com
1  dddd@aaa.com
2  rrrr@aaa.com
3  aaaa@aaa.com
4  oooo@aaa.com), ('ClickedURL',               a
0  aaaa@aaa.com
1  rrrr@aaa.com)])
```

Then join together and change order by subset `[]` and for each column from second check membership by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html), last convert boolena mask to integers.

```
cols = list(dfs.keys())
df = pd.concat({k: v.iloc[:, 0] for k, v in dfs.items()}, axis=1)[cols]

df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(lambda x: df.iloc[:, 0].isin(x)).astype(int)
print (df)
  ReceivedEmail OpenedEmail ClickedURL
0  aaaa@aaa.com           1          1
1  bbbb@aaa.com           0          0
2  cccc@aaa.com           0          0
3  dddd@aaa.com           1          0
4  eeee@aaa.com           0          0
5  ffff@aaa.com           0          0
6  gggg@aaa.com           1          0
7  rrrr@aaa.com           1          1
8  qqqq@aaa.com           0          0
9  oooo@aaa.com           1          0
```